# Web enabling Java console application's JMX beans

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jmx, jconsole

I have built a Java console-based application and exposed key methods via Spring/JMX declarations. Using JConsole, I can invoke these methods but more ideally, I would like to build a management-style web application to provide browser-based access to these methods.

Thanks.

Ashwin

Answer (score 1):

[JBoss has something like this built-in](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/install.html#jmxconsoleintro), and a Google search also suggests [jManage](http://www.jmanage.org/).

Comment: jmx-console from JBoss is pretty cool. I provides a generic web interface to edit all JMX Beans properties and methods.

Comment: I think JBoss' jmx-console monitors only web applications running on the same application server; I could be wrong so I will look more into it. jManage sounds more viable, and it looks like I can use it to monitor multiple applications. Thanks!

Comment: That was an unstated assumption in mentioning it, that you'd need to run your application within JBoss to utilize that feature.

Answer (score 0):

[jminix](http://code.google.com/p/jminix/) looks like an off-shelf solution for my needs. Thanks everyone for responding!